# Storing string variable contains with comma and new line as value to CSV in R

Tags: r

i am trying to save this two objects into a csv file , this i used inside function that is why i used append write.table

```
dt <- "Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, \"Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for \",  : \n  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT * FROM rAXA (ORA-00942: table or view does not exist\n)\n"
er <- "error"
er_file <- cbind(er,dt)
write.table(er_file, file = "E:\\Hama_Hex\\Project\\Predictive\\log1.csv",sep=",",
        col.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

but when i execute the above script its not properly saving into csv file, the special character `\n` in `dt` object is creating problem , it making to move new line . i want to store entire line in one cell. Here i am saving in csv format, value has some comma so it got splits and enter into new cell.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the newline characters:

```
write.table(gsub("\\n", "\\\\n", er_file), 
            file = "E:\\Hama_Hex\\Project\\Predictive\\log1.csv",sep=",",
            col.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

This will replace every `\n` with `\\n`. Note in the above code that you have to escape the `\` characters in order to create a usable regular expression for `gsub`.

Comment: New line problem solved , now its problem with comma(,) , as i am saving in csv file its going into nearer cell .

Comment: @HamaLatha In what sense? Are you trying to open the data in another program (e.g., Excel)? If so, that's an Excel problem, not an R problem.